# Identify Code that loops through Array's

Tags: .net, vb.net

I recently converted a very large VB6 program to VB.Net. The problem is that VB6 used 1 based index and VB.net uses a 0 based index. What I wanted to do was write a program that would go through my source code (which is over 500,000 lines) and find every time an array is iterated through. It would then write the line to a text file, then I could painstakingly go through each case and make sure every array is being read correctly. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: whats with this: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/miscellaneous/article.php/c6975/Migration-Tips-from-VB-6-to-VBNET.htm : "Use of Zero Arrays" - The converter should have handled that for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a combination of streamreaders and streamwriters with some code to achieve your desired result but i don't think it's ideal. (http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/vbNet.html has good tutorials on manipulating text)

```
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("filepath")
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("newfilepath")

Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
    dim strLine as String = objReader.readline()
    objWriter.Write(strLine.replace("string you want to find and replace","new string").replace("other possible strings to replace","and more new strings"))
Loop

objWriter.close()
```

That would create a new file from your old one... That is if you can identify the strings that need replacing and what you can replace them with...? Good luck :)

ps. you can of course add as many replace methods to the end of that string as you like...